# vkCreateInstance() crashes even after updating drivers

Tags: c++, driver, vulkan

I've been using the Vulkan API on Windows for a while without problems. But recently my Vulkan application started having issues. It crashes at `vkCreateInstance()` and outputs this warning:

```
WARNING: dzn is not a conformant Vulkan implementation, testing use only.
```

It looks like a driver issue, so I updated the drivers of the integrated GPU ([AMD](https://www.amd.com/es/support)) and discrete GPU ([Nvidia](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/218113/en-us/)), and updated Vulkan SDK ([LunarG](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home)), but the issue persists. Also, I cannot run Vulkan SDK's demos (like vkCube or vkconfig).

It's worth mentioning that sometimes (not very often) the `vkCreateInstance()` doesn't crash (but the warning is still shown) and execution continues without further problems, rendering everything just fine.

Running older versions of my application (from repository) that worked fine in the past also get this warning and crash. I don't know what else I can do to prevent `vkCreateInstance()` from crashing. This didn't happen ever before.

- Discrete physical device (I pick this): NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU
- Integrated physical device: AMD Radeon (TM) Graphics
- Vulkan SDK version: 1.3.275.0.
- OS: Windows 11

**Edit (solution)**:

Apparently, the issue is caused by the "[OpenCL, OpenGL, and Vulkan Compatibility Pack](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9NQPSL29BFFF?hl=en-US&gl=US)". After uninstalling it, the problem was solved.

This issue started the 29/01/2024, the same day this pack was installed (probably automatically by "Windows Update"), and it affected many people using Vulkan. Its purpose is to allow OpenCL, OpenGL, and Vulkan apps to run on Windows 10 or 11 PCs that doesn't have the required hardware drivers installed by default. However, it looks like it contained a bug that caused this issue.

Comment: Why are you trying to run on `dzn`? That's an experimental driver built for Mesa. If you're building on/for native windows you'd just use the drivers supplied by your card vendor (NVIDIA in this case) not dzn.  It looks like you're running on something like WSL, not windows. The warning isn't an error, it's a warning.

Comment: @Cubic, you're right, that's not an error message, it's a warning. Word fixed.

Comment: @Cubic, I'm not trying to run on ```dzn```. At least, that's not what I want. I use the Nvidia GPU for creating the logical device (```vkCreateDevice```), so I should be using the Nvidia driver. However, note that device creation happens way after Vulkan instance creation (```vkCreateInstance```) and the ```dzn``` warning.

Comment: I'm using Windows, really. I don't know, maybe the warning has nothing to do with the crash. Maybe ```dzn``` was detected (somehow) and the warning was output just in case I use that driver, but the crash reason could be very different.

Comment: There's no "just in case", you *are* using that driver.

Comment: @Blindy, how is it possible? The warning is output BEFORE I choose the device I want to use (Nvidia GPU). AFAIK, at that time, I'm still not using any GPU.

Comment: @AnselmoGPP You're picking a vulkan implementation at link time. How that deals with multiple different devices is up to the implementation. All I can tell you is that, _right now_, you're using the `dzn` implementation. This is more of a system configuration issue, we can't really help with that, not without knowing a lot more details about what you're doing on your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem too. I had been working on it for 5 hours. Then I saw that the "OpenCL™, OpenGL®, and Vulkan® Compatibility Pack" in the Windows Store had been updated yesterday. When I uninstalled it, the problem was solved.
https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9NQPSL29BFFF?hl=en&gl=US